# Custom keys in Crashlytics seems to be lost between activities

Tags: android, crashlytics

I wanted to add custom keys in Crashlytics reports so I done something like this:

Activity 1:

```
Crashlytics.start(this);
```

Activity 2:

```
Crashlytics.setString(Constants.MY_KEY, "my value");
```

...
    Crashlytics.setString(Constants.MY_KEY, "my overwritten value");

Activity 3:

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().crash();
```

The problem is that there is no MY_KEY displayed in the crash info. ONLY if I set it in Activity 1 but is not getting overwritten on Activity 2.

Is there any workaround to make this work ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with this approach. Just make sure your custom key in Activity 2 is read before crash happens. You can put a break point or log it to make sure the setString method is called.